# Прогон всех запросов через файл ,с использованием .htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, drupal

вообщем чищу сайты от вирусов.

Вирус раскидывает по проекту файлы плохие(вроде бы не мешают , но сайт при перенаполнении такими гадостями падает)

Поставил блокировщик плохих запросов, он вроде блокирует, но файлы все равно появляются. Логи говорят что перед появлением происходят гет запросы на сайте(но это не точно) после этого файлы опять появляются .

Блокировщик прописан в index.php думаю его как-то в htacsess прописать, но не знаю как

Должен сначала обрабатываться запрос через блокировщик, потом переходим на index
(сейчас блокировщик в index)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h88eak6d/ htacsess

Comment: А в чём вопрос?